# A script to remove unneeded files

Tags: python, file-system

The hard drive in my dev box is running out of space so I wrote this little script to try and free up space until I get a new drive.

**My Concerns**

1. Is the code pythonic?
2. Does the code go against any best practices?

---

```
import glob
import os
import psutil
import shutil

PATHS = ['/var/log/*', '/tmp/*', '/home/ricky/Downloads/']

USAGE = psutil.disk_usage('/').percent

if os.geteuid() != 0:
    exit("You need to have root privileges to run this script.")

def flatten(alist):
    if alist == []:
        return []
    elif type(alist) is not list:
        return [alist]
    else:
        return flatten(alist[0]) + flatten(alist[1:])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for path in flatten(map(glob.glob, PATHS)):
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            os.remove(path)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            shutil.rmtree(path)

    print "Usage Before {}\nUsage After {}".format(USAGE, psutil.disk_usage('/').percent)
```

Example Output:

```
ricky@ricky-OptiPlex-330:~/Projects/Python 
$ sudo python cleanup.py 
Usage Before 83.5
Usage After 82.1
```

Comment: Why not just do `sudo rm -rf /var/log/* /tmp/*`?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success
This will work on Windows Mac and Linux

Comment: Windows has [`rd /s /q`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DELTREE#Obsolescence).

Comment: Note that your code will quite possibly break some daemons and logging. This is bad code not in terms of style but in terms of how it does what it does.

Comment: /tmp directory sometimes contains files that are USED by system as it runs. Logging function of some daemons will break if you just remove the files they write to. Logfile sizes are controlled using rotate logs and similar daemons. /tmp directory is usually emptied by system as you reboot.

Comment: Also note that this will NOT work on Windows at all, since Windows uses different directory structure

Answer (score 3):

- Move your code inside a function rather than doing things at module level to make it re-useable. Your function could accept a list of paths either through a function call or through command line arguments instead of a global list of paths.
- [Keep standard library, third party imports separate](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).
- You could use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) instead of your flatten function. Also use [`glob.iglob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) to get an iterator instead of list of files to save memory.

  ```
  for path in chain.from_iterable(glob.iglob(path) for path in PATHS):
      ...
  ```
- For comparing types use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) instead of comparing types using `is`. `is` won't work in case of multiple-inheritance. Read: [Differences between `isinstance()` and `type()` in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549801/846892)